How to convert .wat text into .wasm binary inside a browser
Surprisingly, wabt depends on fs under the hood, which is obviously not available inside a browser.
I'm working on an online compiler which translates source code into WAT, so precompilation on the server side is not possible.
Any ideas?

The Readme in the project’s repository links to a browser demo of wat2wasm.

@jsejcksn I see the web app with the example but can't find the actual source code for it. From what i see in both wabt and wat2wasm packages is that they require fs. So mb they just send wat to server and receive wasm from it. If it is possible to use wabt inside a browser, can You provide a code snippet? Thanks.

^ "I see the web app with the example but can't find the actual source code for it": The CSS, HTML, and JS for every web application are plain text — you can view the source in your browser's dev tools. (or — for example — in Chromium browsers you can navigate to view-source:https://webassembly.github.io/wabt/demo/wat2wasm/)

@jsejcksn why ask on stackoverflow if anyone can just reverse-engineer any program? Lol

If that helps, the Wasm reference interpreter can readily be build into a plain JS library that can encode and decode the Wasm text format.
